# How can i validate data entered in the form with the existing data in the database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can i compare data entered in the form with data in the database?.

I have InternalContacts table in this table i have two fields ProductCodeFrom and ProductCodeTo to associate product with Internal Contacts, when Creating new record i would like to validate if the new  range doesn't overlap with the existing

I have this code to get all contacts

```
var getallinternalContacts = await InternalContactsService.GetInternalContacts();
```

I these two fields in my view

```
 <div class="col-sm-6">
     <h5>Product Code From</h5>
     <input asp-for="ProductCodeFrom " type="text" class="form-control w-75" id="ProductCodeFrom " maxlength="50" />        
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h5>"Product Code Thru"</h5>
     <input asp-for="ProductCodeTo" type="text" class="form-control w-75" id="ProductCodeTo" maxlength="50" />
 </div>
```

In my action class i used `ModelState` to validate others as shown below, I would like to add the above validation validation

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid || (internalContactToCreate.ProductCodeRangeFrom > internalContactToCreate.ProductCodeRangeThru))
            {
                if (internalContactToCreate.ProductCodeRangeFrom > internalContactToCreate.ProductCodeRangeThru)
                    ModelState.AddModelError("ProductCodeRangeFrom", "From must be less than To value.");
                return View();
            }
```

Comment: Can you explain more about range overlapping? give some example

Comment: @Always_a_learner how are you?, Hope you having a good weekend, ya so let say i assign ProductCode From 100 - 120 to be managed by InternalContact A when i enter a new record lets say i enter 110 and assign it to InternalContact B since i already assign 100-120 to be managed by InternalContact A and 110 is number between 100 and 120, i can't assign productcode 110 to InternalContact B since that is in in the range assigned to InternalContact A . Do that make sense?

Comment: Got yr points..soon i will post answer..

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/) to validate your binding models.

Assuming that you have a `ProductCodeBindingModel`:

```cs
public ProductCodeBindingModel
{
  public int ProductCodeFrom { get; set; }
  public int ProductCodeTo { get; set; }
}
```

Then, create a validator and add the `LessThan` rule on `ProductCodeTo`:

```cs
public class ProductCodeBindingModelValidator : AbstractValidator<ProductCodeBindingModel>
{
  public ProductCodeBindingModelValidator() {
    // Make sure that ProductCodeFrom < ProductCodeTo
    RuleFor(x => x.ProductCodeFrom)
      .LessThan(x => x.ProductCodeTo);
      .WithMessage('From must be less than To value.');
  }
}
```

You can see more about the `LessThan` rule [here](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/built-in-validators.html#less-than-validator).

Answer (score 0):

You should apply remote validation for this. refer [Razor Remote Validation](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/validation/remote-validation) article.

Tweak your code as below and make changes to accommodate database need.

Code-behind -

```
   [PageRemote(
   ErrorMessage = "!!! Range Exist !!!",
   AdditionalFields = "__RequestVerificationToken",
   HttpMethod = "post",
   PageHandler = "CheckProductCode"
   )]

    [BindProperty]
    public int ProductCodeFrom { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public int ProductCodeTo { get; set; }

    public JsonResult OnPostCheckProductCode()
    {
        // check here prodcut range from database
        var existingRange = new[] { 100, 120 };
        var valid = !existingRange.Contains(ProductCodeTo);
        return new JsonResult(valid);
    }
```

View :

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h5>Product Code From</h5>
        <input asp-for="ProductCodeFrom " type="text" class="form-control w-75" id="ProductCodeFrom " maxlength="50" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ProductCodeFrom"></span><br>
        <h5>"Product Code Thru"</h5>
        <input asp-for="ProductCodeTo" type="text" class="form-control w-75" id="ProductCodeTo" maxlength="50" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ProductCodeTo"></span><br>
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```